# Change text color of datepicker buttons below datepicker android

Tags: android, xml, datepicker, styles, themes

I am trying to change the different colors auf my datepicker dialog in android. I am using AppCompat. I could already change the background color of the header and the color that marks the currently selected year. I tried a lot to change the color of the 'cancel' and 'ok' button as well as the the color of the bubble that marks the currently selected day.
At the moment it looks like this:

[Current date picker style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSKBG.jpg)

I have styled my datepicker this way:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item></style><style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/green_transparent</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for my problem?
I have already tried to change the text color and different button attributes but nothing could change the buttons.

Answer (score -3):

By default, it uses the colorAccent property. So, include it in your theme as below.

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">button_color</item>
</style>
```